# Get envelope.i.e overlapping time spans

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics, timespan

I have a table with online sessions like this (empty rows are just for better visibility):

```
ip_address  | start_time       | stop_time
------------|------------------|------------------
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 08:00 | 2016-04-02 08:12
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 08:11 | 2016-04-02 08:20

10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 09:00 | 2016-04-02 09:10
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 09:05 | 2016-04-02 09:08
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 09:05 | 2016-04-02 09:11
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 09:02 | 2016-04-02 09:15
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 09:10 | 2016-04-02 09:12

10.66.44.22 | 2016-04-02 08:05 | 2016-04-02 08:07
10.66.44.22 | 2016-04-02 08:03 | 2016-04-02 08:11
```

And I need the "envelop" online time spans:

```
ip_address  | full_start_time  | full_stop_time
------------|------------------|------------------
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 08:00 | 2016-04-02 08:20
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 09:00 | 2016-04-02 09:15
10.66.44.22 | 2016-04-02 08:03 | 2016-04-02 08:11
```

I have this query which returns desired result:

```
WITH t AS 
    -- Determine full time-range of each IP
    (SELECT ip_address, MIN(start_time) AS min_start_time, MAX(stop_time) AS max_stop_time FROM IP_SESSIONS GROUP BY ip_address),
t2 AS
    -- compose ticks
    (SELECT DISTINCT ip_address, min_start_time + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE AS ts
    FROM t
    CONNECT BY min_start_time + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE <= max_stop_time),
t3 AS 
    -- get all "online" ticks
    (SELECT DISTINCT ip_address, ts
    FROM t2
        JOIN IP_SESSIONS USING (ip_address)
    WHERE ts BETWEEN start_time AND stop_time),
t4 AS
    (SELECT ip_address, ts,
        LAG(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY ip_address ORDER BY ts) AS previous_ts
    FROM t3),
t5 AS 
    (SELECT ip_address, ts, 
        SUM(DECODE(previous_ts,NULL,1,0 + (CASE WHEN previous_ts + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE <> ts THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY ip_address ORDER BY ts ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) session_no
    FROM t4)
SELECT ip_address, MIN(ts) AS full_start_time, MAX(ts) AS full_stop_time
FROM t5
GROUP BY ip_address, session_no
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

However, I am concerned about the performance. The table has hundreds of million rows and the time resolution is millisecond (not one Minute as given in example). Thus CTE `t3` is gonna be huge. Does anybody have a solution which avoids the Self-Join and "CONNECT BY"?

A single smart [Analytic Function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one, too. I tested it the best I could, I believe it covers all the possibilities, including coalescing adjacent intervals (10:15 to 10:30 and 10:30 to 10:40 are combined into a single interval, 10:15 to 10:40). It should also be quite fast, it doesn't use much.

```
with m as
        (
         select ip_address, start_time,
                   max(stop_time) over (partition by ip_address order by start_time 
                             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as m_time
         from ip_sessions
         union all
         select ip_address, NULL, max(stop_time) from ip_sessions group by ip_address
        ),
     n as
        (
         select ip_address, start_time, m_time 
         from m 
         where start_time > m_time or start_time is null or m_time is null
        ),
     f as
        (
         select ip_address, start_time,
            lead(m_time) over (partition by ip_address order by start_time) as stop_time
         from n
        )
select * from f where start_time is not null
/
```

Comment: Nice solution, I don't see any issues either.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - If you still care about this type of problem, I found that Stew Ashton has a better solution on his blog. It should be about twice as fast as mine.  https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/merging-overlapping-date-ranges/

Comment: Great approach. Yes, it should be faster since it does not contain `UNION ALL`. I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

Please test this solution, it works for your examples, but there may be some cases I didn't notice. No connect-by, no self-join.

```
with io as (
  select * from (
    select ip_address, t1, io, sum(io) over (partition by ip_address order by t1) sio
      from (
        select ip_address, start_time t1, 1 io from ip_sessions
        union all 
        select ip_address, stop_time, -1 io from ip_sessions ) )
    where (io = 1 and sio = 1) or (io = -1 and sio = 0) )
select ip_address, t1, t2
  from (
    select io.*, lead(t1) over (partition by ip_address order by t1) as t2 from io)
  where io = 1
```

Test data:

```
create table ip_sessions (ip_address varchar2(15), start_time date, stop_time date);
insert into ip_sessions values ('10.10.10.10', timestamp '2016-04-02 08:00:00', timestamp '2016-04-02 08:12:00');
insert into ip_sessions values ('10.10.10.10', timestamp '2016-04-02 08:11:00', timestamp '2016-04-02 08:20:00');
insert into ip_sessions values ('10.10.10.10', timestamp '2016-04-02 09:00:00', timestamp '2016-04-02 09:10:00');
insert into ip_sessions values ('10.10.10.10', timestamp '2016-04-02 09:05:00', timestamp '2016-04-02 09:08:00');
insert into ip_sessions values ('10.10.10.10', timestamp '2016-04-02 09:02:00', timestamp '2016-04-02 09:15:00');
insert into ip_sessions values ('10.10.10.10', timestamp '2016-04-02 09:10:00', timestamp '2016-04-02 09:12:00');
insert into ip_sessions values ('10.66.44.22', timestamp '2016-04-02 08:05:00', timestamp '2016-04-02 08:07:00');
insert into ip_sessions values ('10.66.44.22', timestamp '2016-04-02 08:03:00', timestamp '2016-04-02 08:11:00');
```

Output:

```
IP_ADDRESS   T1                   T2
-----------  -------------------  -------------------
10.10.10.10  2016-04-02 08:00:00  2016-04-02 08:20:00
10.10.10.10  2016-04-02 09:00:00  2016-04-02 09:15:00
10.66.44.22  2016-04-02 08:03:00  2016-04-02 08:11:00
```

Comment: Fails if you insert also a row as this: `INSERT INTO IP_SESSIONS VALUES ('10.10.10.10', TIMESTAMP '2016-04-02 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2016-04-02 09:16:00');`

Comment: ...because we have two sessions starting at 9:00 in this case. Change `union all` to `union` (which may decrease performance) or add `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` in third line.

Comment: UNION instead of UNION ALL will not work, if you have two intervals from 9:00 to 9:12 and from 9:00 to 9:15, you will pick up the shorter interval and miss the 9:12 to 9:15 interval. Suggestion: try not to use the same name (io) for tables and columns. One more thing, this solution may miss things like 9:00 to 9:12 and 9:12 to 9:18; presumably the result should be 9:00 to 9:18. Possible fix - in the definition of sio, in the over clause, change the ordering to "order by t1, io desc".

Answer (score 0):

I think using `lag()` and cumulative sum is going to have much better performance:

```
select ip_address, min(start_time) as full_start_time,
       max(end_time) as full_end_time
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_et >= start_time then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by ip_address order by start_time) as grp
      from (select s.*,
                   lag(end_time) over (partition by ip_address order by end_time) as prev_et
            from ip_seesions s)
           ) t
group by grp, ip_address
order by 1, 2;
```

gives result:

```
ip_address  | full_start_time  | full_stop_time
------------|------------------|------------------
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 08:00 | 2016-04-02 09:15
10.10.10.10 | 2016-04-02 09:05 | 2016-04-02 09:12
10.66.44.22 | 2016-04-02 08:03 | 2016-04-02 08:11
10.66.44.22 | 2016-04-02 08:05 | 2016-04-02 08:07
```

Comment: Does not work. IP 10.10.10.10 was offline from 08:20:01 till 08:59:59.  IP 10.66.44.22 was online from 08:03 till 08:11 (I edit your answer with result of your query)