# select not available hours

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i have the falowing table machines_hist

```
Contract      start_time                Fin_time
C1       2016-01-01 05:10:10     2016-01-01 15:10:10
C1       2016-01-02 10:16:20     2016-01-03 12:14:10
C1       2016-01-05 10:16:20     2016-01-10 17:11:10
C1       2016-02-05 02:16:20     2016-01-06 19:18:10
```

On one contract there are several machines. Each machine has different start time and finish time. The intervals may overlap. I have to do a report which will show how many hours in contract per month machines were not working...

Is it possible?
Any sugestion...

**Additional information**: The table shows downtime for the machines. In a larger table, there may be a column showing which specific machine is down, but that is irrelevant for this problem; we need calculations per contract, not per machine. If there are overlaps, the "common" downtime between two or more machines should not be double-counted; two machines down simultaneously counts the same as one machine being down.

Comment: more or less do a datediff() between the start and fin times to get an active time span, sum the time spans to get total active time, and then subtract from (24 hrs/day  * days/month) to get total inactive time. Or did you want to know which *time spans* each machine was inactive in?

Comment: It is not per machine. Is per contract on month. I have to find  the hours on all machines in contract that no one machine was working...

Comment: Do you need a total number of hours per contract?

Comment: What format are the dates in? yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-dd-mm? I ask because it seems like yyyy-mm-dd, but then in the last row, how is the fin_time BEFORE the start_time?

Comment: i need total number of hours per contract. If ia get this value i need to div by all hours in mont and then i will get percent of unavailable in contract. The date format is YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

Comment: If date format is yyyy-mm-dd how can you have fin_date of January 6 when start_date was February 5 (same year)?   **WAIT**... did you mean to type 2016-**01**-05 for start date in the last row? Is that a typo?

Comment: More questions... Does your table show times when the machines were NOT working, or when they were working? I assume this shows downtime (NOT WORKING). Also, if the intervals overlap, for example if three machines were not working for the exact same interval, should that interval be considered only once, or should it be considered three times, as if the intervals were on different days?

Comment: This show time when machine was nt working. For three machines interval sholud be considered once. This is the bigest problem... for example i can be in january. one day working, next day off, nex day wroking, next day of.. etc.. I't realy hard. I have no idea. I do not even know it is possible from this table select this infrmation...

Comment: It is possible, I solved something similar a few weeks ago, I will look it up and write back with a solution. More questions: What if an interval begins before Jan.1 (for example 10 pm on Dec. 31) and continues till Jan. 1 at 1:30 am? I guess that should be assumed to be 2 hours in Dec. and 1.5 hours in Jan. - right? Then - I assume there are several contracts possible, and you want the report for different months? One report for contract C1 with all the months in 2015? Or month is Jan. 2016 and you want all the contracts for that one month?

Comment: @mathguy, yes I had almost the same question, see other answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387048/get-envelope-i-e-overlapping-time-spans

Comment: @mathguy that should be assumed to be 2 hours in Dec. and 1.5 hours in Jan. - right :)Report will be run only for 12 mont in year. Ther is imposoble to run report from example 11.2015 to 4.2016 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup** (test data):

```
SQL> select * from machines_hist;

CONTRACT   START_TIME          FIN_TIME
---------- ------------------- -------------------
C1         2015-12-30 05:10:10 2016-01-01 15:10:10
C1         2016-01-02 10:16:20 2016-01-03 12:14:10
C1         2016-01-25 10:16:20 2016-02-10 17:11:10
C1         2016-01-05 02:16:20 2016-01-06 19:18:10
C2         2016-01-15 12:20:22 2016-01-17 13:40:10
C2         2016-02-23 04:13:50 2016-02-24 02:20:44
C3         2016-02-20 10:13:20 2016-02-20 11:16:40
C4         2015-12-23 20:00:00 2015-12-24 12:23:00
C5         2015-12-31 22:34:00 2016-02-23 00:00:00
9 rows selected.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.33
```

**Query**: (notice the bind variables - normally provided by application):

```
with a as (select to_date(:mon || '-' || :yr, 'MON-yyyy') as month_start from dual),
     b as (select add_months(month_start, 1) as month_end from a),
     c as (select contract, greatest(month_start, start_time) as st, 
                            least(month_end, fin_time) as fin
           from machines_hist join a on fin_time >= month_start 
                              join b on start_time <= month_end),
     m as (select contract, st,
                   max(fin) over (partition by contract order by st
                            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as m_time
           from c
           union all
           select contract, NULL, max(fin) from c group by contract),
     n as (select contract, st, m_time
           from m
           where st > m_time or st is null or m_time is null),
     f as (select contract, st as st_downtime,
                  lead(m_time) over (partition by contract order by st) as fin_downtime
           from n)
select contract, max(:mon || '-' || :yr) as mth, 
       round(100 * sum(fin_downtime - st_downtime)/
          ((select month_end from b) - (select month_start from a)), 2) as downtime_pct
from f
where st_downtime is not null
group by contract
order by contract
/
```

**Bind variables** (illustrating SQL*Plus interface - each program has its own mechanism):

```
SQL> variable yr number
SQL> variable mon varchar2(3)
SQL> begin :mon := 'JAN'; :yr := 2016; end;
  2  /
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```

**Output** (notes: script saved as "downtime.sql", called through SQL*Plus; percentage of downtime in the month expressed as 22.3 representing 22.3% etc.; if a contract had NO downtime, it is not included in the output)

```
SQL> start downtime

CONTRACT   MTH          DOWNTIME_PCT
---------- ------------ ------------
C1         JAN-2016            32.24
C2         JAN-2016             6.63
C5         JAN-2016              100
3 rows selected.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.19
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE machines_hist ( Contract, start_time, Fin_time ) AS
SELECT 'C1', CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 05:10:10' AS DATE ), CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 15:10:10' AS DATE ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-01-02 10:16:20' AS DATE ), CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-01-03 12:14:10' AS DATE ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-01-05 10:16:20' AS DATE ), CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-01-10 17:11:10' AS DATE ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-01-05 02:16:20' AS DATE ), CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-01-06 19:18:10' AS DATE ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AS DATE ), CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AS DATE ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-04-01 00:00:00' AS DATE ), CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-04-07 00:00:00' AS DATE ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-04-05 00:00:00' AS DATE ), CAST( TIMESTAMP '2016-04-10 00:00:00' AS DATE ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH times ( contract, boundary_time, type ) AS (
  SELECT Contract,
         Start_time,
         1
  FROM   machines_hist
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Contract,
         fin_time,
         -1
  FROM   machines_hist
  ORDER BY 1, 2
),
bounds ( contract, boundary_time, type, boundary_value ) AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM( type ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Contract
                            ORDER BY boundary_time ASC, type DESC
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
  FROM  times t
),
end_times ( contract, start_time, type, boundary_value, end_time ) AS (
  SELECT b.*,
         LEAD( CASE WHEN type = -1 AND boundary_value = 0 THEN boundary_time END )
           IGNORE NULLS
           OVER ( PARTITION BY Contract ORDER BY boundary_time )
           AS end_time
  FROM   bounds b
),
filtered_end_times ( contract, start_time, end_time ) AS (
  SELECT contract,
         start_time,
         end_time
  FROM   end_times
  WHERE  type = 1
  AND    boundary_value = 1
),
month_boundaries ( start_month, end_month ) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC( MIN( start_time ), 'MM' ),
         CASE WHEN MAX( end_time ) = TRUNC( MAX( end_time ), 'MM' )
              THEN MAX( end_time )
              ELSE TRUNC( MAX( end_time ), 'MM' ) + INTERVAL '1' MONTH
              END
  FROM   filtered_end_times
),
months ( start_month, end_month ) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS( start_month, LEVEL - 1),
         ADD_MONTHS( start_month, LEVEL)
  FROM   month_boundaries
  CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( start_month, LEVEL) <= end_month
)
SELECT contract,
       start_month,
       end_month
         - start_month
         - SUM( LEAST(end_month,end_time)-GREATEST(start_month,start_time) )
           AS days_not_working
FROM   months
       INNER JOIN
       filtered_end_times
       ON ( start_time <= end_month AND end_time >= start_month )
GROUP BY
       contract,
       start_month,
       end_month
ORDER BY
       contract,
       start_month
```

**Output**:

```
CONTRACT START_MONTH         DAYS_NOT_WORKING
-------- ------------------- ----------------
C1       2016-01-01 00:00:00       23.8800926 
C1       2016-02-01 00:00:00                0 
C1       2016-03-01 00:00:00               31 
C1       2016-04-01 00:00:00               21
```