# PL/SQL: Finding islands in overlapping date ranges defined by a start and an end

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a pretty large data set consisting of persons and the start and end dates of their insurance. Each person can have multiple records with overlapping dates. I need to find the start and end of each "island" for every person.

For example:

```
    SKP_PERSON  DATE_INSURANCE_START    DATE_INSURANCE_END   SKP_INSURANCE
1   1           7.11.2015               1.1.3000             1
2   1           7.11.2015               1.1.3000             2
3   2           10.4.2015               1.8.2016 23:59:59    3
4   3           28.3.2016               1.1.3000             4
5   4           5.12.2015               31.12.2015 23:59:59  5
6   4           5.12.2015               1.5.2016 23:59:59    6
7   4           1.2.2016                1.5.2016 23:59:59    7
8   5           15.1.2016               2.3.2016 23:59:59    8
9   5           15.3.2016               2.6.2016 23:59:59    9
```

The result I need would be something like this:

```
    SKP_PERSON  DATE_INSURANCE_START    DATE_INSURANCE_END   
1   1           7.11.2015               1.1.3000             
2   2           10.4.2015               1.8.2016 23:59:59    
3   3           28.3.2016               1.1.3000             
4   4           5.12.2015               1.5.2016 23:59:59    
5   5           15.1.2016               2.3.2016 23:59:59    
6   5           15.3.2016               2.6.2016 23:59:59
```

I have managed to find a solution by joining all possible dates (from min(start) to max(end)) to each person and finding a lag and lead value for each day - but there's too many records and the date ranges are too large so it takes too long. Is there a more effective solution using PL/SQL?

EDIT:
The query I tried (simplified):

```
WITH table1 AS (
SELECT d.dtime_day, COUNT(i.dkp_insurance), i.skp_person 
FROM date d --a date table, contains a record for every day
JOIN insurance i ON d.dtime_day BETWEEN i.DATE_INSURANCE_START AND i.DATE_INSURANCE_END    
GROUP BY d.dtime_day, i.skp_person
)
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT distinct skp_person, 
CASE WHEN LAG(dtime_day) OVER (PARTITION BY skp_person ORDER BY dtime_day) <> dtime_day -1 THEN dtime_day END AS start,
CASE WHEN LEAD(dtime_day) OVER (PARTITION BY skp_person ORDER BY dtime_day) <> dtime_day +1 THEN dtime_day END AS end
FROM table1 t1)
WHERE start IS NOT NULL OR end IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY skp_person
;
```

Comment: Can you provide the SQL you've already tried?  Also, are there any indexes on these tables?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how are the tables in the data warehouse I'm using indexed - SKP_INSURANCE is a primary key though. I'll add the code in edit.

Comment: I answered a similar question a few moths ago, please take a look. From the code you wrote I see that you can handle SQL, all you need is ideas for algorithms (approaches to solve the problem); if you think you can use my solution but you need further help, please say so. Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387048/get-envelope-i-e-overlapping-time-spans/36408651#36408651

Comment: Looking at your sample data you can improve perfomance dramatically when handling open intervals (end=1.1.3000) different way.

Comment: @mathguy: I'm going to have to test it properly but it looks like this might be exaclty what I needed - I didn't even have to change anything except column names. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted my older solution to this situation (see comment to the original question). The silly +1/86400 (adding a second) is needed to deal with the weird end date/times in your table.

```
with
     inputs ( skp_person, date_insurance_start, date_insurance_end ) as (
       select 1, to_date('7.11.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('1.1.3000'           , 'dd.mm.yyyy')             from dual union all
       select 1, to_date('7.11.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('1.1.3000'           , 'dd.mm.yyyy')             from dual union all
       select 2, to_date('10.4.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('1.8.2016 23:59:59'  , 'dd.mm.yyyy  hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 3, to_date('28.3.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('1.1.3000'           , 'dd.mm.yyyy')             from dual union all
       select 4, to_date('5.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2015 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  from dual union all
       select 4, to_date('5.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('1.5.2016 23:59:59'  , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  from dual union all
       select 4, to_date('1.2.2016' , 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('1.5.2016 23:59:59'  , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  from dual union all
       select 5, to_date('15.1.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('2.3.2016 23:59:59'  , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  from dual union all
       select 5, to_date('15.3.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('2.6.2016 23:59:59'  , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  from dual
     ),
     m ( skp_person, date_insurance_start, m_date ) as (
       select  skp_person, date_insurance_start, 
               max(date_insurance_end + 1/86400)
               over (partition by skp_person order by date_insurance_start
                    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
         from  inputs
       union all
       select  skp_person, null, max(date_insurance_end + 1/86400)
         from  inputs
         group by skp_person
     ),
     f ( skp_person, date_insurance_start, e_date ) as (
       select  skp_person, date_insurance_start,
               lead(m_date) over 
               (partition by skp_person order by date_insurance_start)
       from    m
       where   date_insurance_start > m_date 
          or   date_insurance_start is null   or m_date is null
     )
select skp_person, date_insurance_start, e_date - 1/86400 as date_insurance_end
from f where date_insurance_start is not null
;
```

**Output**:  (using my NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings)

```
SKP_PERSON DATE_INSURANCE_STAR DATE_INSURANCE_END
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 07.11.2015 00:00:00 01.01.3000 00:00:00
         2 10.04.2015 00:00:00 01.08.2016 23:59:59
         3 28.03.2016 00:00:00 01.01.3000 00:00:00
         4 05.12.2015 00:00:00 01.05.2016 23:59:59
         5 15.01.2016 00:00:00 02.03.2016 23:59:59
         5 15.03.2016 00:00:00 02.06.2016 23:59:59
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the results look correct. The solution from comments almost worked, it just sometimes didn't connect groups starting and ending in consecutive dates.

Comment: Yes - the old solution needed to be adapted for the odd end dates, that's what I did in the solution posted here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea:

- Use `lag()` or some other method to identify when an island begins
- Construct a flag that is 1 when the island begins
- Run a cumulative sum
- Reaggregate

The resulting query looks like this:

```
select skp_person,
       min(date_insurance_start) as date_insurance_start,
       min(date_insurance_end) as date_insurance_end
from (select t.*,
             sum(isIslandFlag) over (partition by skp_person order by date_insurance_start) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when exists (select 1
                                      from t t2
                                      where t2.skp_person = t.skp_person and
                                            t2.date_insurance_start between t.date_insurance_start and t.date_insurance_end
                                     )
                         then 0 else 1
                   end) as IsIslandFlag
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by skp_person, grp;
```

Note:  This method is not fool-proof, but it works in most real-world circumstances.  For instance, if you have multiple policies that start on the same day, then it would need to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: I'm going to have to look at the query properly but it doesn't work as it is. SKP_PERSON 4 from the example returns 5.12.2015 and 31.12.2015. Thanks anyway, if nothing else it's an inspiration.

Comment: Are your values stored as dates or strings?