# ORACLE SQL - Connecting overlapping timeframes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
 ╔══════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
 ║ Emp# ║ StartDate ║ EndDate ║
 ╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
 ║    1 ║ 1Jan      ║ 15Jan   ║
 ║    1 ║ 3Jan      ║ 5Jan    ║
 ║    1 ║ 10Jan     ║ 20Jan   ║
 ║    1 ║ 23Jan     ║ 25Jan   ║
 ║    1 ║ 24Jan     ║ 27Jan   ║
 ╚══════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

I need to create a query that will connect the overlaps perfectly so that for each possible **calendar date** there is at most 1 Row per employee. The output should be as follows:

```
 ╔══════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
 ║ Emp# ║ StartDate ║ EndDate ║
 ╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
 ║    1 ║ 1Jan      ║ 20Jan   ║
 ║    1 ║ 23Jan     ║ 27Jan   ║
 ╚══════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

I tried to do it with Self-Joins but I would need X self-joins for X overlaps. I would appreciate any direction to finding a solution. 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please post what you tried so far.

Comment: Search for "gaps and islands problem".

Comment: I used a self-join such that I would check if there would be an overlap between two time-frames - if there was then I would pick the minimum start date and max end date. Then I would select the minimum start date for each end date and the max end date for each minimum start date. However, this leaves me with holes if I have two timeframes which are both overlapped by a third timeframe

Comment: Check this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387048/get-envelope-i-e-overlapping-time-spans

Comment: You need more than what you stated. You also need the least number of rows per employee, consistent with what you stated so far. Otherwise, a solution that simply displays one row PER DAY would also work.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - there is an important difference between this problem and the older one though. In the older problem, "time" was continuous, so if an interval ends at 10:30, the next interval starts at 10:30 as well. With pure dates, "time" is discrete, so if an interval ends on Jan 4, the next interval starts on Jan 5. To coalesce adjacent intervals, the "old solution" will need to be tweaked to take this into account.

Comment: @mustaccio - as presented, this is not a gaps and islands problem. It could be made into one, by unwrapping the individual dates from each interval, doing a UNION (which will also remove duplicates), then applying gaps and islands methods as you suggest, but that doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the older solution (from one of the Comments), adapted to work for pure dates. You may want to compare the different solutions offered here to see which is most efficient for your actual data; different solutions may be best for different situations.

NOTES:  I used your input data and created some more for testing. It is assumed that your data is valid (all dates are valid, they have a time component of `00:00:00`, and `enddate` is always greater than or equal to `startdate`). The solution does not include the `inputs` factored subquery, it's shown below only for testing. I did NOT order the results by `emp#` and `startdate` (the output may be misleading in that regard); if you do need such ordering, you will need to add it explicitly. Note the use of the `date` literal in the test data. The output shows dates in my current Session settings; if you need a specific format, use `to_date()` with the desired display format model.

QUERY:

```
with
     inputs ( emp#, startdate, enddate ) as (
       select 1, date '2016-01-01', date '2016-01-15' from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-01-03', date '2016-01-05' from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-01-10', date '2016-01-20' from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-01-23', date '2016-01-25' from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-01-24', date '2016-01-27' from dual union all
       select 2, date '2016-01-31', date '2016-02-28' from dual union all
       select 2, date '2016-03-15', date '2016-03-18' from dual union all
       select 2, date '2016-03-19', date '2016-03-19' from dual union all
       select 2, date '2016-03-20', date '2016-03-20' from dual
     ),
     m ( emp#, startdate, mdate ) as (
         select     emp#, startdate,
                    1 + max(enddate) over (partition by emp# order by startdate 
                             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
         from       inputs
         union all
         select     emp#, NULL, 1 + max(enddate) 
           from     inputs 
           group by emp#
     ),
     n ( emp#, startdate, mdate ) as (
         select emp#, startdate, mdate 
         from   m 
         where  startdate > mdate or startdate is null or mdate is null
     ),
     f ( emp#, startdate, enddate ) as (
         select emp#, startdate,
                lead(mdate) over (partition by emp# order by startdate) - 1
         from   n
     )
select * from f where startdate is not null
```

OUTPUT (for data in the `inputs` CTE):

```
  EMP# STARTDATE  ENDDATE          
------ ---------- ----------
     1 01/01/2016 20/01/2016
     1 23/01/2016 27/01/2016
     2 31/01/2016 28/02/2016
     2 15/03/2016 20/03/2016
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the idea:

1. Identify where a group begins.  Use `exists` with `case` for this purpose.
2. Assign a flag to those dates.
3. Accumulate the flag so all overlapping time periods have the same value.
4. Use this for aggregation

This method works well, although it needs a slight tweak when two time periods have the same start date that begins an overlapping period.  So:

```
select emp#, min(startdate) as startdate, max(enddate) as enddate
from (select t.*,
             sum(OverlapFlag) over (partition by Emp# order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when exists (select 1
                                      from t2
                                      where t2.Emp# = t.Emp# and
                                            t2.startdate < t.startdate and
                                            t2.enddate + 1 >= t.startdate
                                     )
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as OverlapFlag
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by emp#, grp;
```

Comment: Great solution.

Comment: Great solution, but it fails to coalesce adjacent intervals. So for example if emp#1 had intervals 1Jan-3Jan and 4Jan-9Jan, the result should be 1Jan-9Jan; however, the solution provided here leaves them separated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use PL-SQL here. Start with sorting the records by StartDate, then with every further date see if StartDate still is in the range given. If so, check whether EndDate extends the range.

Here is the package header:

```
create or replace package mypackage as
  type type_mytable is table of mytable%rowtype;
  function get_ranges return type_mytable pipelined;
end mypackage;
```

The package body:

```
create or replace package body mypackage as
  function get_ranges return type_mytable pipelined as
    v_current mytable%rowtype;
  begin
    for rec in
    (
       select *
       from mytable
       order by emp#, startdate
    ) loop
      if rec.emp# = v_current.emp# and rec.startdate between v_current.startdate 
                                                         and v_current.enddate + 1 then
        if rec.enddate >  v_current.enddate then
          v_current.enddate := rec.enddate;
        end if;
      else
        if v_current.emp# is not null then
          pipe row(v_current);
        end if;
        v_current := rec;
      end if;
    end loop;
    pipe row(v_current);
  end get_ranges;
end mypackage;
```

Calling the function:

```
select * from table(mypackage.get_ranges) where emp# = 1;
```

Comment: I would use PL/SQL only if a pure SQL solution doesn't exist or is inefficient. Not the case here. (A link to a pure SQL solution to a closely related question has been provided in a Comment to the original question.) Self-serving for me to say so here, since I provided the solution in the older thread - but I would say the same thing if it weren't my solution.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. I'd go with the SQL solution myself, too. The PL/SQL can be very readable though with appropriate comments here and there :-)