# Time spent at multiple (same) location - window function, maybe?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Each color is a location. This is ordered by the Start date and needs to stay that way to find first location, second, etc. The location can show up more than once for various reasons. I need the earliest Start date and last End date for each "window", or ID, LOC. Hopefully the example below is legible and makes this clear. I'm working in SQL Server. Can be done in Oracle. I've tried various window funtions...first_value, last_value, lead, lag, partitioned different ways with different combinations and no luck. The actual data will have many different ID's so that should be part of the partition. 
Thank you for any help.

This is the sample data:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|ID   |LOC   |START              |END                |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|45334|RED   |2015-08-26 17:26:21|2015-08-26 20:17:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-08-26 20:17:50|2015-08-30 21:01:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-08-30 21:01:49|2015-09-02 15:19:00|
|45334|YELLOW|2015-09-02 15:19:33|2015-09-02 21:46:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-02 21:46:36|2015-09-05 19:48:00|
|45334|BLUE  |2015-09-05 19:48:26|2015-09-05 20:33:00|
|45334|YELLOW|2015-09-05 20:33:11|2015-09-05 21:27:00|
|45334|BLACK |2015-09-05 21:27:38|2015-09-07 16:48:09|
|45334|BLACK |2015-09-07 16:48:09|2015-09-08 18:30:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-08 18:35:13|2015-09-10 11:15:23|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-10 11:15:23|2015-09-10 20:32:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-10 20:32:57|2015-09-16 15:22:58|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-16 15:22:58|2015-09-17 14:02:00|
|45334|YELLOW|2015-09-17 14:02:28|2015-09-17 17:04:00|
|45334|BLACK |2015-09-17 17:04:25|2015-09-18 11:36:03|
|45334|BLACK |2015-09-18 11:36:03|2015-09-18 21:48:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-18 21:49:05|2015-09-21 11:22:29|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-21 11:22:29|2015-09-21 18:54:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-21 18:54:50|2015-09-23 13:39:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-23 13:39:25|2015-09-23 16:12:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-23 16:12:00|2015-09-23 16:25:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-23 16:25:37|2015-10-02 15:13:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-10-02 15:13:00|2015-10-02 15:13:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-10-02 15:13:00|2015-10-02 15:13:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-10-02 15:13:00|2015-10-02 15:13:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-10-02 15:13:00|2015-10-02 15:13:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-10-02 15:13:00|2015-10-02 15:13:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-10-02 15:13:00|2015-10-02 15:13:00|
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

This is what it should look like:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|ID   |LOC   |START              |END                |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|45334|RED   |2015-08-26 17:26:21|2015-08-26 20:17:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-08-26 20:17:50|2015-09-02 15:19:00|
|45334|YELLOW|2015-09-02 15:19:33|2015-09-02 21:46:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-02 21:46:36|2015-09-05 19:48:00|
|45334|BLUE  |2015-09-05 19:48:26|2015-09-05 20:33:00|
|45334|YELLOW|2015-09-05 20:33:11|2015-09-05 21:27:00|
|45334|BLACK |2015-09-05 21:27:38|2015-09-08 18:30:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-08 18:35:13|2015-09-17 14:02:00|
|45334|YELLOW|2015-09-17 14:02:28|2015-09-17 17:04:00|
|45334|BLACK |2015-09-17 17:04:25|2015-09-18 21:48:00|
|45334|GREEN |2015-09-18 21:49:05|2015-10-02 15:13:00|
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Which DBMS are you using? The logic for this is vastly different on different platforms. I can't speak for Oracle but in sql server this looks like a typical gaps and islands problem that has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times.

Comment: What do you define as "window"?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387048/get-envelope-i-e-overlapping-time-spans

Comment: Sean...I've thought about gaps and islands but haven't wrote the code for it...if you notice the end date is the start date for the next record so I didn't really see any gaps. Something to consider though.

Comment: Wernfried...I consider a window to be each Loc or group of Loc's. So for Green, there are 4 separate windows...does that make sense?

Comment: No, if you say "I consider a window to be each Loc" then you would get only 5 rows back. One each for red, green, yellow, blue, black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign flag as `1` when the location changes. Use `sum(flag) over (...)` to create grouping column. Finally group data:

```
select id, min(loc), min(start_), max(end_)
  from (
    select a.*, sum(flag) over(order by start_) grp
      from (select t.*, case when loc <> lag(loc) over (order by start_) 
                             then 1 else 0 end flag from t) a )
  group by id, grp
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6478d6561afa1aa18092ed12a5638ef4)</sup>**

Tested in Oracle. Add `partition by id` in final code.

Comment: Ponder...this looks like exactly what I need. I'll test it out on the rest of the data...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html):

```
select id,
       loc,
       to_char(min(start_), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') grp_start_time,
       to_char(max(end_), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') grp_end_time
from   (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by id order by start_, ROWNUM)
                 - row_number() over (partition by id, loc order by start_, ROWNUM) grp
        from t)
group by id, loc, grp
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c32eb44b5f603455f5face3dc496167)

N.B. I had to add `rownum` into the order by of the `row_number()` analytic functions because you have rows in your sample data that have the same start and end times. If the start times are all different across the rows per id and loc, you would't need `rownum` in the order by.

If I were you, I'd try both solutions and see which one is more performant for your data, etc. (I'd be interested to learn your results; I suspect either there is little in it, or Ponder's answer has the edge.)